# Can Jersey resources classes be instantiated in Spring Boot if they're external?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey

I'm developing a Spring Boot app using Jersey for Rest.
The app will regularly have Rest controller and supporting classes added to it, basically adding small, specific logic at specific endpoints.
I'd like to be able to drop jars containing Jersey controllers into a directory specified by loader.path and have them created (including Spring auto-wiring) by just restarting the server.
Some Jersey resources form the base of the application and these are working fine because I've registered them via a ResourceConfig class but I'd really like to add resources without requiring a rebuild of the app.
Is this possible? I'm failing to get the resources created, I'm not even sure they're in the classpath.
In application.properites, I added:

```
-Dloader.path=lib/,resources/
```

and I've copied the jars into these folders, but they don't get instantiated.

Anybody got any ideas?

Comment: By sheer fluke (or a randomly trying combinations of things), I seem to have found a solution and it's basically what I found in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140784/spring-boot-is-it-possible-to-use-external-application-properties-files-in-arbi
My command line is:
java -Dloader.path=file:///C:/code/extraJars/, target/mainJar.jar -jar target/mainJar.jar .....