# Spring-Boot app is not honoring -Dloader.path

Tags: java, spring-boot, classloader, spring-boot-maven-plugin

My Spring boot app (v2.1.1.RELEASE) is packaged using below plugin and layout :

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>my-service-${project.version}</finalName>
                        <mainClass>com.my.app.MainClass</mainClass>
                        <layout>ZIP</layout>
                    </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I am using below launch script :

```
java -Dloader.path=/path/to/config/dir/ -jar my-service-1.0.jar
```

In one of dependencies which my app has, below code is used to read the external xml config files (e.g. hbase-site.xml) :

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filename);
```

which is why I am trying to make those files available using loader.path but the app still doesn't read the files present on the provided dir. Am I missing anything else?

Already referred : [Spring Boot: Is it possible to use external application.properties files in arbitrary directories with a fat jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26140784/3266029)

[Spring Boot Executable Jar with Classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39716796/3266029)

Comment: Have you checked if the directory structure is correct, based on this docs, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: Also try using   @PropertySource("file:config.properties")

Comment: @Anil these files are xml config files required for dependencies. I need to pass this externally so that it can be made available by spring boot runtime. I updated the question also. So in this case "PropertySource" will not work as it expects the .properties file or something similar which has key-value pair in expected format.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be the problem of getSystemResource, try to use getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path)