# Spring Boot - How to specify an alternate start-class? (Multiple Entry Points)

Tags: java, spring, jar, spring-boot

I want to add an alternate entry point to my Spring-Boot application.  I would prefer to keep this as a fat jar.  Is this possible?

According to their [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html), the property `loader.main` specifies the name of the main class to launch.

I tried `java -jar MyJar.jar --loader.main=com.mycompany.AlternateMain` but the start-class specified in my pom.xml was still run (and if I remove this from the pom.xml then I error during the packaging).

Alternatively, I tried `java -cp MyJar.jar com.mycompany.AlternateMain` but I don't know of a good way to add all the nested jars to the classpath.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:  Here is the solution that I used**

As jst suggested, I changed my launcher to use the PropertiesLauncher.  I did this by modifying the configuration of my spring-boot-maven-plugin.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
    <layout>ZIP</layout>
    ...
```

The `<layout>ZIP</layout>` [triggers Spring Boot to use the `PropertiesLauncher`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168310/how-to-specify-the-launcher-in-spring-boot-gradle).

I created my fat jar (mvn package) then called the alternate main like this:

```
java -jar -Dloader.main=com.mycompany.AlternateMain MyJar.jar
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Spring Boot simply uses the JAR's Manifest to specify the main class and classpath. So I think the real question here is can there be more than one Main Class in an executable JAR? That question is also asked/answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3976514/953327

Comment: What are you intending to accomplish with this?  Do you want to create multiple applications from within Spring Boot?

Comment: @FGreg I can access the alternate main using the second command that I noted, which matches the answer in the SO thread you link to.  In order to use this successfully, I would have to figure out how to add my nested jars to the classpath.

Comment: @Makoto I do not want to create multiple applications with this.  It's actually a proof of concept that I am doing now, but I have used multiple entry points in the past for a variety of reasons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't believe that property would apply in your case. There are 3 different "Launchers" (go back to the docs and see). If you are building a jar it uses the JarLauncher class. If you switch it to PropertiesLauncher then loader.main would be useful.

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

Comment: This sounds very promising, but my results are the same.  To use the PropertiesLauncher, I configured the spring-boot-maven-plugin, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21328440/2860319.  I could see in my manifest that it worked and the PropertiesLauncher was now being used, but the loader.main property specified via command line did not change the start-class... hmmmm

Comment: I was adding the properties incorrectly, I'll update my post with what I did.  Thanks for the great suggestion!

Answer (score 12):

I took a different approach and use a command line parameter to determine which class to use as my SpringApplication class.  I only have a single main() method, but different Application classes with different configurations that are used based on a command line param.

I have a single class with a main() in it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app;
    if( ArrayUtils.contains(args, "--createdb")){
        app = new SpringApplication(CreateDB.class);
        args = (String[])ArrayUtils.add(args, "--spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create");
    } else {
        app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
    }

    app.setWebEnvironment(false);
    app.setShowBanner(false);
    app.addListeners(new ConfigurationLogger());

    // launch the app
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = app.run(args);

    // finished so close the context
    context.close();
}
```

But I have 2 different SpringApplication classes: Application.class & CreateDB.class.  Each class defines a different `@ComponentScan` path as well as different `@EnableAutoConfiguration` options and different `@Configuration` options.  Finally, based on my command line arguments, I can decide whether to programatically enable additional profiles/etc.

In my case, I want a different launcher to just create the DB schema and exit, so I've forced the command line parameter.

Comment: This is where I was heading too, presumably `CreateDB` and `Application` exist in separate packages, thus enabling you to use `@ComponentScan` with `basePackages` set to that package?

Comment: Indeed that is possible.  In my case, they are actually in the same package, but my `@ComponentScan()` explicity sets different base packages to scan with different exclusion rules.  It also allows you to have different `@AutoConfiguration()` options, different Config classes, etc.  And quite frankly - I find it much easier to do this way than to use the launcher and launcher parameters to specify long class names; this allows me to abstract it any way I want.  I've basically packaged 2 separate SpringBoot apps (which share common classes) in the same jar.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest having a single `main` but using Spring profiles (or configuration properties) to select one or other "entry point" `@Configuration` class.

Comment: Can you provide an example, please?