# How to specify the Launcher in Spring Boot Gradle?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, launcher

There three launcher in Spring Boot: JarLauncher/PropertiesLauncher/WarLauncher.
For executable jar, JarLauncher will be used by default. Now I want to use PropertiesLauncher instead so that I could use external classpath. How could I specify that is spring boot gradle plugin?

Accoring to D3.1 of this doc [D.3.1 Launcher manifest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.x/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-launching), I can specify the main class in MANIFEST.MF like this:

```
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
Start-Class: com.mycompany.project.MyApplication
```

However, in Spring Boot Gradle, the following code snippet actually specifies the Start-Class, not the Main-Class:

```
springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.sybercare.HealthServiceApplication"
}
```

Do I need to create the MANIFIEST.MF manually or there is a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the `layout` property:

```
springBoot{
    mainClass = "com.sybercare.HealthServiceApplication"
    layout = "ZIP"
}
```

`layout = ZIP` Triggers SpringBoot to use the `PropertiesLauncher`

Comment: thank you so much @pczeus. I was looking for this solution but could not find it easily. where did you find docs for that?

Answer (score 1):

The layout property defaults to a guess based on the archive type (jar or war). For the PropertiesLauncher the layout is ZIP (even though the output might be a jar file).

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.M2/maven-plugin/usage.html

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are outdated now. The current answer seems to be:

```
tasks.getByName<BootJar>("bootJar") {
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class" to "org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher")
    }
}
```

as per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.configuring.properties-launcher